# Trying to build a map/hashmap in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, hashmap, salesforce

I'm trying to run a query in javascript and pass the results to other querys to pull more data. I also want to be able to display this data all in one table so I'm trying to get the results arranged in a javascript map but I seem to be having issues.

**This is being built inside of salesforce.com with their AJAX toolkit**

The code I have is...

```
var cn = Query("select id, LastName, FirstName, Middle_Name__c, Gender__c, HomePhone, Birthdate, Birth_City__c," +
    "Birth_Country__c, SSN_Encrypted__c, Provider_NPI_ID__c, Primary_Specialty__c," +
    "Practicing_Specialty__c, Title, GlobalProviderID__c from contact where Name like " +
    "'%" + sBox + "%'");
var PFA;

for (var i = 0; i < cn.length; i++) {
    var x = new Array();
    var PFA = Query("select id, First_Scheduled_Date__c, Region__c " +
        "from Provider_Facility_Associations__c where Provider__c='" + cn[i].Id + "'");
    m['cn'] = cn[i];
    m['PFA'] = PFA;
    m[i] = x;
}

console.log(m['cn']);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Holy SQL injection batman!

Comment: That's enough internet for me for today.

Comment: It's using the salesforce.com AJAX toolkit, it shouldn't be a concern.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a basic javascript object as a map.

So

```
var map = {};
map["key1"] ="value1"
map["key2"] = "value2"
```

will create an object like this:

```
map = {
  key1:"value1",
  key2:"value2"
}
```

When you pass an integer `i` to your m object it will try to treat it as an array though rather than an object.

You have deeper issues than this though since you should not be running SQL queries from javascript.  That will allow anyone to run arbitrary queries on your database when accessing your website.

Comment: It's using the salesforce.com ajax toolkit so injection shouldn't be a concern as far as I know. I think my code is pretty close to your example, this doesn't work though.

Answer (score 1):

Please read up about how [relationships](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) work in Salesforce and their specific "joins" that look weird at the beginning but actually save your bacon many many times in common development situations like that.

```
SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName,
    (SELECT Id, First_Scheduled_Date__c, Region__c 
    FROM Provider_Facility_Associations__r)
FROM contact 
WHERE Name LIKE '%Smith%'
```

(note the "__r" in the "subquery")

This will give you Contacts and each of them will have a "field" called Provider_Facility_Associations__r that will be an array of items (or just empty array if nothing found).

Salesforce security model is not a silver bullet, you **should** worry about performance and [SQL injections](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm). People can't use them to delete stuff they shouldn't but they can learn information you didn't intend to expose.

Last but not least - this will perform better and be more secure if you'd have the query server side and just pass the variable (part of contact's name) there. This can be apex exposed as webservice or if you're in Visualforce - action function, JavaScript remoting... There are plenty of options!

I'm not saying the AJAX toolkit is an abomination... But it should be used very rarely if at all. It's an artifact from so-called SControl days and with introduction of Visualforce (hmm... 4 years now?) many of it's use cases can be done faster & in more secure way.

Comment: You're right, trying to leverage queryMore ;)
The problem with the relationships is some are children and some are reference objects. Some objects don't know a relationship even exits because the child is looking up to it.

Comment: I'd still do it in one go and exhaust related lists. Set batch size to 2000 and if that's not enough - call `queryMores` on children? http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm#understanding_results (scroll a bit down). And if there's no way to make subquery because rel. name is null - cheat ;) Nobody stops you from making a new "field" in the returned contact and plugging the results of separate query there...

Answer (score 0):

Running SQL from JS is a bad idea usually unless you are using a sql-lite localstorage engine of some sort. Anyways, I believe your problem may be that your m's and x's are mixed up. Also, running queries in a for loop where using an `IN` in the second query or a `JOIN` and just doing one query would probably be better.